# How to open Native SMS default inbox from Cordova Application

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have created application in Cordova, I need to open default SMS inbox by clicking on inbox icon as I am just showing. I need to open phone default inbox by clicking on that  button. I have tried many code, but unable to open inbox.

I want to open native SMS default inbox from Cordova application. For ex. if I click on a button in my Cordova app, then it redirects to my phone's default native SMS App inbox. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this so caveat emptor, but you could look at:
https://github.com/lampaa/com.lampa.startapp

This contains example code for starting an SMS app:

`startApp.set
({
    "action":   "ACTION_MAIN",
    "category": "CATEGORY_DEFAULT",
    "type":     "vnd.android-dir/mms-sms"
}).start();`

Keep in mind that for Android, phone manufacturers use custom ROMs that may have different SMS apps, or users may install their own, so not sure if this is the best approach.

What I'd be more inclined to do is use a Cordova SMS plugin to put some simple screens together to show SMS messages inside your app. For example:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-sms

This has an option to list messages, which should be easy to display, and you can possibly filter for the messages you're interested in, if that's helpful.